# My shinydashboard app works on my machine but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard, shinyapps

and thanks for any help!

I keep getting the same error message when trying to publish the app on shinyapps.io:

**The application failed to start (exited with code 1).**

I have already commented the *setwd()* and *library(shiny)* as I have learned from other posts, but so far no luck. This is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

[image]

I am new to this, so any support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are using an absolute file path in your script. shinyapps.io won't understand a file path specific to your machine.

Instead, try putting the files you need to read in a folder (e.g. 'InputFiles') and put that folder in the same place as your scripts. Change your scripts to refer to files using relative file paths like: `'InputFiles/file1.csv'`.

When you run the code locally make sure to set the working directory to the same directory your scripts are in. When you publish to shinyapps.io make sure to include your scripts and the 'InputFiles' directory.

Here's a great explanation of how these work: https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Storage.html#Storage

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you can you should post your solution as an answer in case anyone else comes here with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution came to me after reading Thomas's post. I had an *R script* (which did all the statistics and plots for my dashboard) stored in the same folder where the shiny *UI* and *server* were stored. After moving this script file to a different folder, the problem was solved. I do not quite understand why this fixed the issue, but I hope this article helps people facing similar issues.

Comment: If you added that script to shinyapp.io along with the app scripts (UI, server) shinyapps.io may have tried to execute it, and it had an absolute file path which caused the whole thing to fail.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!